# CMake project Link to opencv failed for libopencv_highgui.so referencing unresolved avformat_ffmpeg symbols

Tags: c++, cmake

My project link to opencv lib but the opencv lib my system has depends on libavcodec-* libs.
And after I added these libs via target_link_libraries with the correct full path, I also checked some of these symbols, turns out the deps do carry them, but it still complains unresolved symbols provided by these deps, which means the error message remains the same, here are the error messages.

```
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `av_malloc@LIBAVUTIL_FFMPEG_54'
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `av_register_all@LIBAVFORMAT_FFMPEG_56'
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `avcodec_close@LIBAVCODEC_FFMPEG_56'
```

I checked the link command by `cmake --build . --verbose`, its like this:

```
/usr/bin/c++ \
CMakeFiles/myproject.dir/imgproc.cc.o \
-o \
myproject \
 \
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.6.1 \
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.9 \
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so.2.4.9 \
_deps/oatpp-build/src/liboatpp.a \
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so \
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavformat-ffmpeg.so \
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavutil-ffmpeg.so \
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libswscale-ffmpeg.so \
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5.6.1 \
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.6.1 \
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so.2.4.9 \
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9 \
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.9 \
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4.9 \
-lpthread \
-latomic
```

**Update**: Checked the cv lib and the deps file info.

```
file /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56.60.100 
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56.60.100: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=e534adc24d3ba924851e5a11dc9eee87d5008d36, stripped
file /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9 
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=2a6d6bf1318da7a8593b96359b3c8a66008744ee, stripped
```

1. Does the `version 1 (SYSV)` and `version 1 (GNU/Linux)` have something to do with the link failure?
2. Preserve libs' order in CMake build (comments)?
   The cv lib is from find_package but not for the avcodec-ffmpeg, the package does not provide a cmake config, So it's currently from find_library. In CMake how do I get the LINK_LIBS in its order in the link command?

Comment: Probably version mismatch. What `nm -D libavcodec-ffmpeg.so | grep avcodec_close` tells you?

Comment: `nm -D /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so | grep avcodec_close
00000000000d4780 T avcodec_close` and  `ll /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Sep  7  2020 /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so -> libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56.60.100` seems match?

Comment: The link order matters, the ffmpeg libraries need to be after the opencv ones. If you use the targets generated by `find_package` it'll do everything for you. Please show a [mre]

Comment: The cv lib is from find_package but not for the avcodec-ffmpeg, the package does not provide a cmake config, So it's currently from find_library

Comment: if you use the target generated from `find_package` it should automatically bring in any required dependencies

Comment: No, It didn't, only find_package for OpenCV cmake gave nothing on libavcodec-ffmpeg, unresolved symbols as in question's error message.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: But system varies, currently no simple way to make a minimal reproducible example, it fails on my target system which is a old ubuntu family and it's an aarch64, the OS software repo is broken and long outdated, it just succeeds on my dev laptop. @Alan

Comment: I ran the link command manually with reordered libraries with opencv libs before its deps, still the same error. @Alan, I'm afraid it's not due to the libs' order.

Comment: Please reopen my question if possible.

Comment: Undefined reference in the **existed** **shared** library means that the **library itself is wrong**, or it is used in the wrong environment. That problem is mostly unrelated to your project. By using `ldd` for `libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9` library find out, which exact libraries (paths!) it depends on. Then among those libraries try to find the one, which provides missed symbols, with **exact versions** (`av_malloc@LIBAVUTIL_FFMPEG_54`). Most likely the symbols in those libraries differes from the required ones.

Comment: if you can post a [mre] then we can reopen the question though likely the duplicate still applies

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, you're right, ldd shows `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4)`, thank you, Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: You need to either replace library `libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56` with the one which provides version information, or replace library `libopencv_highgui.so.2.4` with the one which doesn't require version. The simplest way would be installing both libraries from the same **package repository**: normally such repositories provide compatibility guarantees between their libraries.